# geometric progression calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a given geometric progression,  a1 equals 30, q in absolute value is smaller than one, and the sum of all arguments in even positions is 11.25. what is the value if q?

attempt at a solution:   for the even arguments, a1 is 30q, q is 2q and we know the sum in infinity is 11.25. plugging that to the summation formula for this kind of progression yields 3/14. official answer is 1/3 . any suggestions?

Comment: @bluesh34 corrected...

Comment: good point...I meant that for the geometric progression of the even numbers of the entire progression a1 is 30q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the terms are numbered starting with $a_1$, so that $a_2=a_1q$, $a_3=a_1q^2$, and in general $a_n=a_1q^{n-1}$. Thus, the subseries of even-numbered terms is

$$11.25=a_1q+a_1q^3+a_1q^5+\ldots=a_1q\sum_{n\ge 0}q^{2n}=a_1q\sum_{n\ge 0}(q^2)^n=\frac{10q}{1-q^2}\;,$$

and $11.25(1-q^2)=10q$. This is just a quadratic in $q$, so you can solve it. (It even factors nicely once you simplify it to a form with integer coefficients, though of course you can also just use the quadratic formula.) You’ll find that one solution is the answer that you were given, and the other is unusable, because it’s too big.

Comment: @Bak1139: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The progression is $30+30q+30q^2\cdots$

Consider the sum of the numbers in the even position. The first term is $30q$ (in position 2), and the common ratio is $q^2$.

The sum is $\displaystyle{\frac{30q}{1-q^2} = \frac{45}{4}}$

Solving the resulting quadratic gives $\displaystyle{q = \frac{1}{3}}$